# how to get the sum of a series of decimel numbers strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have to write a program sums the numbers of a string.

There's a sample code , I wrote

```
s = '1.23, 2.12, 3.45'
num1 = [:4]
num2 = [5:9]
num3 = [10:]
sum = num1+ num2+ num3
print sum
```

But that's not efficient . If I take the string from the user then, How could I write that code where I can separate the numbers from that s individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one liner solution. Split every item by `,` (comma and space) then convert those to floats and sum them

```
s = '1.23, 23.5, 56.77'
print(sum([float(x) for x in s.split(", ")]))
#81.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it in 3 steps.

First: Split, with the [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#split) function, the string in the `,`

```
s.split(',')
```

Second: Apply a `float` conversion, with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function, for every element from the new list

```
map(float, s.split(','))
```

Third: Sum all elements from the list, with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function.

```
res = sum(map(float, s.split(',')))
print res
```

Comment: TIL that `float` trims surrounding spaces in its input before processing.

Answer (score 0):

first split it by your sign , then map it to your target

```
x = s.split(',')
y = map(float,x)
print sum(y)
```

Comment: Thanks , i got the ans